# Sudo command not found (every sudo command is not working) (Mac)

Tags: macos, ubuntu, sudo

I am trying to use 'Sudo' command for solving firewall problem.

so I typed 'sudo ufw allow 22' and 'sudo ufw allow 22/tcp' on my bash terminal.

but terminal keep saying "sudo command not found"

***:~ ***$ sudo ufw allow 22
Password:
sudo: ufw: command not found

I tried to change path on bash_profile.
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

until 5 hours ago sudo command was working well and ssh too.

but after I changed /etc/network/interfaces information, all of sudden I couldn't use ssc and sudo.

Is there anyone can help me? It will be really appreciated.

Comment: The error message in your question sais it's ufw that is not found... `**:~ **$ sudo ufw status sudo: ufw: command not found`

Try to sudo ls to see if it's ok

Comment: thanks! i edited. but sudo ufw status also not working.....